# Jenkins pipeline script exit status -1 for docker maven image

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I try to build my project inside of a docker container, the image looks like this:

```
FROM maven:3.3.9-jdk-8
WORKDIR mvnBuildDir
ENTRYPOINT ["mvn"]
```

if I run my container like below everything works fine.

```
docker run -v /home/user/Worspace/myMavenProject:/mvnBuildDir myMaven3 clean package
```

But if I try this in my *Jenkinsfile* I got an error which is telling me nothing.
Jenkinsfile:

```groovy
//...
def maven = docker.image("myMaven3");
maven.inside("-v ${workdir}:/mvnBuildDir"){
    stage "build and test"
    sh "mvn clean install"
}
//..
```

Error:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage (build and test)
Entering stage build and test
Proceeding
[Pipeline] sh
[master] Running shell script
+ mvn clean install -s mvnSettings.xml
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop 1fc920c00b46a1038b0f39e2adc6e67f702d48ccf10d3e0bb3514d1cee3a795b
$ docker rm -f 1fc920c00b46a1038b0f39e2adc6e67f702d48ccf10d3e0bb3514d1cee3a795b
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Has anybody have an idea what the problem is here or has anybody another solution how to build my project inside the docker container?
My whole workspace is mapped inside the container, so the problem isn't that pom or something else is not found I think. If I run 'mvn --version' I got the right output.
Thanks so far.

Answer (score -1):

When using docker images I had the behavior that the command ended but the docker was still running, so I had no output.

You could try ton invoke the docker via shell.

`sh 'docker pull myMaven3'`

`sh 'docker run --rm -v ${workdir}:/mvnBuildDir myMaven3 clean install'`

Comment: Jenkins pipeline mounts the source code into the docker container via a volume. I don't think this will work.